# How to add a new button to the form of new opportunity?

Tags: process-builder, custom-button, button, commandbutton, button-overrides

[image]this is the form where i want to add the "save & new quote" button .Is it possible to add a button to the New Opportunity flow? Once the form is felled , I'd like to have the option to click save and create a new quote. "Save & New quote".
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a screen flow and embed it on a contact or account lightning record page. That way you can customize the fields for input and override the screen flow buttons (see: [Override Screen flow's button actions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/390389/override-screen-flows-button-actions)). After the screen flow, use the create records element to create a new quote and specify what values you’d like to use for creation.