# Override Screen flow's button actions

Tags: screen-flow

I'd like to know if we can override screen flow's buttons (Pause, Previous, Finish) to do something else, not what they are originally meant to do.
I basically want to fire an apex method via those buttons.

e.g.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can override the buttons using a custom lwc button. [lightning/flowSupport](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-flow-support/documentation) module provides events that enable a component to control flow navigation and notify the flow of changes in attribute values.

Make sure to add flow target in meta xml file as below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

and the footer component on screen flow and make sure to do uncheck show footer inside configure footer panel at the right bottom of the image.

[image]

The buttons in footer lwc component can look like this:-

```
<footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Submit">
            </lightning-button>
            <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" onclick={handleRefresh} name="refresh" label="Refresh">
            </lightning-button>
  </footer>
```

handle the button click in js file of the lwc component. You can call apex method there. To finish the flow, you can fire this event:-

```
// navigate to the next screen
const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationFinishEvent();
this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
```

A working example you can find here:- [LWC INSIDE FLOW WITH CUSTOM FOOTER](https://salesforcediaries.com/2022/01/06/lwc-inside-flow-with-custom-footer/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. 10/10 thank you!